# Modular equation with unknown exponent on the left side

Tags: modular-arithmetic, matlab

I would like to know, how to input and solve following equation in Matlab:

$2^x \equiv 456 \ (\text{mod}\ 582)$

Is there a way to find $x$ in Matlab?

Comment: I don't know anything about Matlab, but I can say no solution exists to that specific problem if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This equation has no solution: indeed, as $582=6\times 97$, a solution would imply 
$$2^x\equiv 456\equiv 68\mod 97.$$
However, as $2$ has order $48\bmod 97$, this would imply $68^{48}\equiv 1\mod 97$. However  the *fast exponentiation algorithm* shows $68^{48}\equiv -1\mod 97$.

*Added:*

@Mike observed, it's much simpler to consider congruences  mod. $3$: $456\equiv 0\mod 3$, and $2$ is a unit mod $3$, so none of its powers can be congruent to $456  \bmod 3$.

Comment: Much more straightforward to do $2^x\equiv0\pmod3$.  A power of 2 will never be a multiple of 3.

Comment: Oh! yes. Don't lnow why I missed it. Probably because  I only thought mod $6$, and $2$ is a  zero divisor mod $6$, so I looked on the $97$ side. I'll add it to the answer.